# Passing object reference to a method

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

If the Employee reference is made null in the changedetails(), variable id value is retained and NullPointerException is not thrown (Code 1) may be because we just pass a copy of object's reference, but in Code 2 why the variables value has changed

Code 1:

```
public class JavaPassing {
    public static void changedetails(Employee e)
    {
        e=null;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee("Vishal",7);
        changedetails(emp);
        System.out.println(emp.id);
    }
}
```

Code 2:

```
public class JavaPassing {
    public static void changedetails(Employee e)
    {
        e.id=9;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee("Vishal",7);
        changedetails(emp);
        System.out.println(emp.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a fact, where's the question?

Comment: According to SCJP book "any changes to the object that occur inside the method are being made to the object
whose reference was passed". So if we have made the Employee object reference null in the method the actual object reference should also be made null. What am i missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      -------- 
A -->| Object |<-- B
      --------

A.id = 10; // Property of object modified
B.id = 10; // Property of object modified here also

B = null ; // B is set to null
      -------- 
A -->| Object |     B (reference is null)
      --------
```

Here when you set `B` to `null`, `A` is not modified it will continue to point the `Object` in heap.

And that is why it will not throw `NullPointerException` if you will access `id` from reference `A`. All you are confused is between *reference of Object* and *Object in memory*.

In your case, `A` is `emp` and `B` is `e`.

[You can find some good explanation in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1686291)

Answer (score 5):

**`In both cases  Reference 'e' in changedetails() and 'emp' in main() both point to same object.`**

**In code (1)**

In changedetails() when you make e=null; ONLY e STOPS POINTING TO OBJECT. BUT emp CONTINUES TO POINT TO OBJECT. So in main() when you do emp.id value prints and no NullPointerException

**In code (2)**
In changedetails() when you make e.id=9 remember **Both References are pointing to same object** i.e.
'e' in changedetails() and 'emp' in main() point to same object ....
So e.id=9 means change made on same object hence when you do emp.id in main() value is 9

Answer (score 2):

1. In java references to objects are passed by value.

So,

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Employee emp = new Employee("Vishal",7);
    changedetails(emp);  / /object Employee ahs only one reference - "emp"
    System.out.println(emp.id);
}


public void   changedetails(Employee emp1){ // here both emp1 and emp of main() point to the same Employee object.
emp1.setId(100); // now since emp1 also points to same Employee object, the data will be changed.
emp1 = null;// now emp1 points to null. So, only emp is pointing to E,ployee

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument you pass into the method `changedetails()` is a variable of its own, different from the variable `emp` in your `main()` method. They both refer to the same eployee so. Hence if you refer to the employee and change its state, the change is visible in both methods, `changedetails()` and `main()`. But if you assign `null` to the argument variable of the method `changedetails()` this is a local change visible only in that method.

Sidenote: it is considered bad practice to change the value of method arguments. And after leaving the method `changedetails()`, the method arguments are gone, because they live on the stack and not on the heap.